# Combined sql query takes too much time

Tags: mysql, sql

My one query in MySQL takes too much time in executing. In this query, I use IN operator for fetching database from MySQL database.

My query :

```
SELECT *
FROM databse_posts.post_feeds
WHERE
    post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM database_users.user_bookmarks where user_id=3) AND
    post_date < unix_timestamp();
```

In this, both individual queries takes very less time for execution like

```
SELECT post_id FROM database_users.user_bookmarks where user_id=3
```

takes around 400 ms max

and

```
SELECT * FROM databse_posts.post_feeds Where post_date < unix_timestamp();
```

takes 300 ms max

But combining both of queries in one using IN operator it takes around 6 to 7 secs.
Why this taking too much time.
I also write a different same type of queries but all those don't take that amount of time.

Comment: The relational columns has matching indexes? Make a inner join will reduce the time.

Comment: I think if you want to know why it's slow, we are going to need to see the explain plan output.. if you just want a faster solution, timo's answer is probably the most complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a where IN (subselect)  you could try a inner join  on the subselect

```
SELECT *
FROM databse_posts.post_feeds
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM database_users.user_bookmarks 
    where user_id=3
) T on T.post_id = post_feeds.post_id
AND
post_date < unix_timestamp();
```

and be sure you have proper index  on `post_feeds.post_id` and `user_bookmarks.user_id, user_bookmarks.post_id`

Comment: why didn't you remove the subquery entirely, and inner join the two tables/put one combined where clause?

Comment: The indices you suggested don't make sense to me, but in any case I don't think an index could be used when joining to the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

You need to create indexes for the fields `post_feeds`.`post_id`, `user_bookmarks`.`post_id`, `user_bookmarks`.`user_id` and `post_feeds`.`post_date` fields, then use INNER JOIN to let MySQL engine to manipulate the filtering and merging of rows in an efficient way:

```
SELECT
    pf.*
FROM
    databse_posts.post_feeds pf
    INNER JOIN database_users.user_bookmarks ub
        ON ( pf.post_id = ub.post_id )
WHERE
    ub.user_id = 3
    AND pf.post_date < unix_timestamp();
```

Comment: OK, but this still doesn't explain the OP's observations.

Comment: You've see that "what the customer wanted" tyre swing cartoon, right? I think this q is probably one of those

Answer (score 1):

My rough guess here would be that the `WHERE IN` expression is doing something of which you might not be aware.  Consider your full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM databse_posts.post_feeds
WHERE
    post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM database_users.user_bookmarks where user_id=3) AND
    post_date < unix_timestamp();
```

MySQL has to check, for each record, each value of `post_id` and compare it to the list of `post_id` coming from the subquery.  This is much more costly than just running that subquery once.  There are various tricks available at MySQL's disposal to speed this up, but the subquery inside a `WHERE IN` clause is not the same as just running that subquery once.

If this hypothesis be correct, then the following query should also be in the range of 6-7 seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM databse_posts.post_feeds
WHERE
    post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM database_users.user_bookmarks where user_id=3)
```

If so, then we would know the source of slow performance.

Comment: Not the most complex subquery though, is it? I'd expect MySQL's optimiser to have rewritten that one in a heartbeat. Is MySQL really such a low grade DB that it will repeatedly run a subquery presented in an IN clause rather than making a hash table out of a static result set?

Comment: @CaiusJard Look at the accepted solution, which implies that `WHERE IN` was hurting performance in some way.  Yes, MySQL can optimize but apparently there was still a penalty.  The accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question, so I'll leave this up so long as it doesn't get downvoted.

Comment: Indeed, and I disagree that the accepted solution is an acceptable solution too, but that's the problem with the unknowing being the arbeiter of the green tick :)